# Multiple String Matching in R

Tags: r, string, text, text-analysis

Consider A,B,C,D .... as words.
I have two DFs.

### df1:

```
ColA
A B
B C
C D
E F
G H
A M
M
```

### df2:

```
ColB
A B C D X Y Z
C D M N F K L
S H A F R M T U
```

Operation:
I want to search all element of df1 in df2 then append all the matching values in a new column OR may be create multiple rows.

### Output 1:

```
ColB                    COlB
A B C D X Y Z           A,A B,B C,C D
C D M N F K L           C D,M
S H A F R M T U         A,A M
```

### Output2:

```
ColB                   Output
A B C D X Y Z           A
A B C D X Y Z           A B
A B C D X Y Z           B C
A B C D X Y Z           C D
C D M N F K L           C D
C D M N F K L           M
S H A F R M T U         A
S H A F R M T U         A M
```

Comment: Where does the single "A" come from? All the others are elements of `df1$ColA`. Are you sure that's not a mistake?

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694470/string-matching-from-list-in-r/36702098#36702098.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it, although it differs a bit from your expected answer, which I think is wrong.

First set up the input data frames:

```
# set up the data
df1 <- data.frame(ColA = c("A B", 
                           "B C", 
                           "C D",
                           "E F",
                           "G H",
                           "A M",
                           "M"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(ColB = c("A B C D X Y Z",
                           "C D M N F K L",
                           "S H A F R M T"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Next we will form all the pairwise combinations of the things to search with the things to be searched:

```
# create a vector of patterns and items to search
intermediate <- as.vector(outer(df2$ColB, df1$ColA, paste, sep = "|"))
# split it into a list
intermediate <- strsplit(intermediate, "|", fixed = TRUE)
```

Then we can create a function to match the elements for each row of this full combination dataset  The core is the `foundMatch` which returns a logical indicating whether all elements in `ColA` were present in `ColB`.  In your examples, order does not matter, so here we split the elements and look for all of the first to be in the second.

```
# set up the output data.frame
Output2 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, intermediate))
names(Output2) <- c("ColB", "Output")

# here is the core, which does the element matching
foundMatch <- apply(Output2, 1, function(x) {
    tokens <- strsplit(x, " ", fixed = TRUE)
    all(tokens[[2]] %in% tokens[[1]])
})
# filter out the ones with the match
Output2 <- Output2[foundMatch, ]

Output2
##             ColB Output
## 1  A B C D X Y Z    A B
## 2  C D M N F K L    A B
## 3  S H A F R M T    A B
## 10 A B C D X Y Z    E F
## 14 C D M N F K L    G H
## 20 C D M N F K L      M
## 21 S H A F R M T      M
```

Not exactly what you have above but I think it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious for me how your data.frames `df1` and `df2` are built. But you can try to vectorise your data and match both sets.

```
d1 <- sort(as.character(unlist(df1)))
d2 <- sort(as.character(unlist(df2)))
# get the intersection/difference without duplicates
intersect(d1,d2)
setdiff(d1,d2)
# get all values matching with the first or with the second dataset, respectively 
d1[ d1 %in% d2 ]
d2[ d2 %in% d1 ]
```

Comment: This will not deliver desired output