# string matching from list in R

Tags: r, text

I am trying to perform string matching in R using grep.   I have to match df1$ColA to df2$ColA
I have given below inputs and outputs:

### Input:

### df1:

```
ColA
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text6
text7
```

### df2:

```
ColA
text1 text2 text12
text23 text22 text7
```

### Intermediate Output:

```
ColA                    ColB
text1 text2 text12     text1, text2
text23 text22 text7    text7
```

### Final Output:

```
ColA                ColB
text1 text2 text12   text1
text1 text2 text12   text2
text23 text22 text7  text7
```

### Method:

I am currently using

```
test$test <- sapply(df2$ColA, function(x) ifelse(grep(paste(as.character(unlist(df1$ColA)),collapse="|"),x),1,0))
```

It will give me if df1$ColA string is matching with df2$ColA but won't return matching strings. Please advice.

Comment: What are the data structures you have? Why are you using `unlist`? Can you provide `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)` please?

Comment: I have two data frames: df1,df2. I am using unlist as it was the only solution, in my knowledge, which could have provided me the current result. However this apporoach might not the best one. Kindly share your solution.

Comment: I've asked for `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)` IIRC

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want a row of df2 for each time a name on df1 is found on df2?

Comment: @Llopid:
yes, You understood correctly.

Comment: @David: I don't know how to use dput. I can't understand. I am fairly new to R.

Comment: Just run these in console and add the output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
df2 <- matrix(sample(LETTERS)[-1], nrow=5)
df2 <- apply(df2, 1, FUN=function(x) paste(x, collapse=' '))

data <- data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:5], b=df2) ; data

df2 <- sapply(1:nrow(data), function(x) strsplit(as.character(data$b[x]), ' '))

sapply(1:nrow(data), function(x) which(data$a[x] == df2[[x]]))

sapply(1:nrow(data), function(x) data$a[x] == df2[[x]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a semi-vectorised solution based on `match()` that should be fast and produce exactly what you are looking for.  The way to match the items in `df1$ColA` is to tokenise the `df2$ColA` and match `df1$ColA` to each of the tokens.  It then builds up a repetition of the entire (original) `df2$ColA` element, and adds the `df1$ColA` match as `ColB` in the output.

```
# set up the data, which the OP should have done
df1 <- data.frame(ColA = paste0("text", 1:7),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(ColA = c("text1 text2 text12",
                           "text23 text22 text7"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# create a matrix of matches of first to elements of second
matmatrix <- sapply(strsplit(df2$ColA, " "), match, df1$ColA)
# repeat original text in same length as potential match
origdfColArep <- rep(df2$ColA, each = nrow(matmatrix))

# create the results dataset, first the matches of the second part
result <- data.frame(ColA = origdfColArep[!is.na(as.vector(matmatrix))],
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# then add the matching first part
result$ColB <- df1$ColA[na.omit(as.vector(matmatrix))]

result
##                  ColA  ColB
## 1  text1 text2 text12 text1
## 2  text1 text2 text12 text2
## 3 text23 text22 text7 text7
```